# How is it that an OP with a rep of 1 can edit and add text to my answer

Tags: discussion, answers

I posted at somewhat lengthy answer to an OP's original question, and later found out that the OP had edited my answer and added a whole bunch of unnecessary text.

I rejected the edit.

How can the OP with a rep of 1 edit/add to my answer?

Comment: Was this a suggested edit? Anyone can suggest an edit, there's no rep limit. You can even suggest an edit without having an account.

Comment: Which answer are we talking about here?  It'd be good to see the *exact* case youre talking about as well

Comment: The other possibility is that they had 2k rep, edited, and then either 1. lost all that rep (maybe given away via bounties, maybe voting reversals), 2. was suspended, so their rep will be shown as 1 for the duration of the suspension

Comment: [Found it](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/903359)

Comment: Yes, Zanna found it. Forgive me if I've got this backwards... but a user with less than 15 rep cannot leave comments... but they can edit the answer of a 17k user?

Comment: Anyone can suggest an edit. You rejected the edit, and it was never applied. Reviewers would have rejected it if you hadn't. Even anonymous users can suggest edits. The purpose of the suggested edits system is to make it easy to improve posts. This benefit is considered to be worth the cost of reviewers' time to check the quality of suggestions, including some being unwarranted, wrong or destructive.

Comment: In my opinion editing and suggesting an edit are two different things. Keeping this short and simple you need to read [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://askubuntu.com/help/editing)

Answer (score 6):

Too bad you only found out now, but back when you were a rep 1 user, you could edit any post and that was then reviewed in the edit queue by users like David Foerster (I remember David leaving comments, re-editing my edits, declining my edits (oh, wait: that one was Seth!) **:D** ).

And you got +2 for each and every approved edit until you reached 1000 rep gained from edits. These edits include post edits and tag wiki edits (500 edits in total). Tag wiki edits are the editing of tags (not re-tagging a question), i.e. editing/creating a tag or its info in [Tags](https://askubuntu.com/tags) tab.

Remember these rep will be gained if your edit is in peer review queue. That means once you gain 2000 rep in total, you'll stop getting +2 from post edits since [privileges of direct editing](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/edit) are granted at that time. The edits are applied immediately instead of going into peer review queue. And it is also to be noted you can still earn +2 from tag wiki edits until you gain 20k rep and become [***A Trusted User***](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

What you just found out was that when a low rep user edits your post, you get to approve it simultaneously with the edit queue and whoever approves / declines first gets to call the shots: the queue or you...

## :-)

Comment: If you get 2000 rep. before 500 edits you can still earn +2 rep. from edits but those edits will be tag edits only.

Comment: @Kulfy just to clarify, those are tag *wiki* edits (not retags of posts - I'm sure you know that but it might not be so clear to others from your comment) and you stop getting rep for them (assuming you didn't hit 1000 rep gained from edits) when you reach 20k, because then you are allowed to edit tag wikis freely :)

Comment: @Zanna Yeah indeed. Missed the word wiki. I re-read my comment and it is confusing

Comment: @Kulfy: feel free to [edit] my answer!  **:D ;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Edited the answer :-)

Comment: @Kulfy Thank you!  **:-)**